# How can gaseous abundance in ppm be converted to density?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate, atmospheric-chemistry

Consider a measurement of the concentration of a gas such as ozone in Earth's atmosphere in pseudo-units of parts-per-million (ppm). What is needed to convert such a measurement to density of the gas? Do we just need to multiply by the density of air at the altitude that the measurement was taken? If so, this can be done using using the ideal gas law, at least for low altitudes. I'm not sure at higher altitudes where compressibility matters more.

If is is easier, assume that this measurement is constant within a small box.

Answer (score 3):

I think the ppm figure means mole fraction. So, if the CO2 concentration is 400ppm it means the mole fraction for this species is $x=400\times 10^{-6}$. Suppose the mole fraction of the ith species is $x_{i}=N_{i}/N$ where $N_{i}$ is the number of moles of the ith species and $N$ is the total number of moles of the gas as a whole. Let $M_{i}$ be the molar mass of the ith species. The density of the ith species is,
\begin{equation}
\rho_{i}=\frac{M_{i}N_{i}}{V}=\frac{M_{i}N_{i}}{N}\frac{N}{V}=M_{i}x_{i}\frac{P}{RT}
\end{equation}
and the final replacement used the ideal gas law $PV=NRT$.

As an example, for CO2, the molar mass is 0.044kg/mol and the mole fraction is $x=400\times 10^{-6}$. Take the atmospheric pressure as $P=10^{5}$Pa and $T=300$K and the gas constant $R=8.314$J/mol/K so the density of CO2 is,
\begin{equation}
\rho=\frac{0.044\times 4\times 10^{-4}\times 10^{5}}{8.314\times 300}=7\times 10^{-4}kg/m^{3} 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The ppm designation means parts in mass per million parts in total mass.

Consider component A in a gas mixture of A + B. Assume the gas is ideal (it is at high enough temperature or low enough pressure such that non-ideal effects are insignificant). Define molar masses $M_A$, $M_B$, and $M_G$ (for the total gas). Under these conditions, 1 ppm A in the gas means by definition 1 mg A per 1 kg gas total. The molar mass of an ideal gas mixture is obtained by the mole fraction of A $y_A$ as

$$ M_G = y_A\ M_A + (1 - y_A)\ M_B $$

Conversion of any $ppm$ to moles A per total moles is

$$y_A = ppm\ \left(\frac{10^{-3}}{10^3}\right)\left(\frac{M_G}{M_A}\right)$$

leading to

$$M_G = \frac{M_B}{1 - ppm\ 10^{-6}\ (M_B - M_A)} \approx M_B$$

The density of an ideal gas depends $\rho_G^\star$ depends only on pressure, temperature, and molar mass as

$$\rho_G^\star = \frac{p\ M_G}{RT}$$

By example, for 2 ppm NO$_2$ in air, where $M_{air} \approx 28$ g/mol and $M_{NO2} \approx 46$ g/mol.

$$M_G = \frac{46}{1 - 2\times 10^{-6}(46 - 28)} = 46.0016... $$
$$ y_{NO2} = 2\times 10^{-6}\ \frac{46.0016...}{46} = 2.00007.. \times 10^{-6} $$

The exact conversion $y = ppm \times 10^{-6}$ is approached in an ideal gas at low ppm and when no significant difference occurs between the molar masses of the added component and the gas to which the component is added.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest fixed thanks